# Stochastic integration with non-caglad integrand

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

In Oksendal's book on Malliavin calculus. The $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{F}_G$ is defined as the completed one generated by all random variables of the form 
$$
F = \int_0^T\chi_A(t) \, dW(t),
$$
for all $A\subseteq G$, where $G$ can by any Borel set in $[0,T]$

Even the process $\chi_A(t)$ is deterministic, how does one justify such integration? As I know, integrands for stochastic integration is required to be caglad, i.e. is left continuous and has left limit. But $\chi_A(t)$ can be non-caglad, for example when $A=\{t\}$.

Comment: You sure that he is saying that $A$ is any subset of a Borel set $G$? Since $G=[0,\infty)$ is a Borel set, this would mean that we can take any set $A \subset [0,\infty)$.

Comment: G is a Borel set in [0,T]

Comment: My question was about $A$ (.. and not about $G$)

Comment: A is Borel subset of G, sorry

Answer (score 2):

It's not true that stochastic integrals are only defined for caglad integrands. In order to make sense of the stochastic integral, we need that the integrand satisfies a certain "good" measurability property. In case of Brownian motion, the integrand has to be progressively measurable, see e.g. Section 15.5 in the book *Brownian Motion* by Schilling & Partzsch for details.  If you are dealing with deterministic integrands, then this progressive measurability boils down to Borel measurability.

> **Lemma:** Let $f:[0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ be a (deterministic) Borel measurable function such that $\int_0^T f(s)^2 \, ds < \infty$ for all $T>0$. Then the stochastic integral $$\int_0^T f(s) \, dW_s$$ exists for all $T>0$.

Comment: Thanks! Another question is, say f(s) = \chi_{s=t}. Then is this stochastic integral identically zero? in the almost surely sense.

Comment: By asking that I actually want to ask, according to the above definition of \mathcal{F}_G, are they the same sigma algebras when taking G = [0,t) and [0,t]?

Comment: @YuxuanLiu Re your first question: Yes, this follows from Itô's isometry. Re your 2nd question: I can't tell because I'm not sure about the definition, see my comment below your question.